# Querying collections for the id of a collection

Tags: wagtail

I want to filter documents by the collection. I'm able to pull all documents by setting context and adding documents with this query:

```
context['documents'] = Document.objects.all()
```

However this fails

```
context['documents'] = Document.objects.filter(collection='articles')
```

I'm getting an error telling me I have to pass the category id instead of the category name. But how do I find the category id knowing the name? I can't seem to find documentation showing how to query the collections object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [standard Django lookup methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-objects) on the `Collection` model:

```
from wagtail.core.models import Collection

collection_id = Collection.objects.get(name='articles').id
```

In this case, though, you can [incorporate the 'lookup by name' into the filter query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships):

```
context['documents'] = Document.objects.filter(collection__name='articles')
```

Comment: This looks right, except for the import path. How do you figure them out? I'm getting: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wagtail.collection'

Comment: Never mind. I had tried that import earlier and I didn't capitalize Collection. When I put the new import in, I forgot to take out the old and it was clobbering it. It's working now. What is the best way to learn where all imports come from?